# How to declare a user-defined function returning node-set?

Tags: .net, xslt, msxml

I want something like this:

```
<msxsl:script language="C#">
   ??? getNodes() { ... return ... }
</msxsl:script>

<xsl:for-each select="user:getNodes()">
    ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

What return type should i use for `getNodes()` and what should i put in it's body?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle you need to use the XPathNodeIterator to return node sets (as Samjudson says). I take it that the example you gave is a degenerated function, as you do not supply it with any parameters. However, I think it is instructive the see how you *could* fabricate nodes out of thin air.

```
<msxsl:script language="C#">
   XPathNodeIterator getNodes() 
   { 
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
      doc.LoadXml("<root><fld>val</fld><fld>val2</fld></root>");
      return doc.CreateNavigator().Select("/root/fld");
   }
</msxsl:script>
```

However, typically you would want to do something in your function that is not possible in xslt, like filtering a node set based on some criteria. A criteria that is better implemented through code or depends om some external data structure. Another option is just that you would to simplify a wordy expression (as in the example bellow). Then you would pass some parameters to you getNodes function. For simplicity I use a XPath based filtering but it could be anything:

```
   <msxsl:script language="C#">
       XPathNodeIterator getNodes(XPathNodeIterator NodesToFilter, string Criteria)
      {
         XPathNodeIterator x = NodesToFilter.Current.Select("SOMEVERYCOMPLEXPATH["+Criteria+"]");
         return x;
      }
   </msxsl:script>
   <xsl:for-each select="user:getNodes(values/val,'SomeCriteria')">
    ...
  </xsl:for-each>
```

Hopes this helps,
Boaz

Answer (score 2):

A quick google for C# xslt msxml revealed a link to the following page which gives many examples of extending XSLT in microsoft environments.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302079.aspx

Specifically the section on Mapping Types between XSLT and .Net gives you exactly the information you need:

W3C XPath Type -  Equivalent .NET Class (Type)

- String - System.String
- Boolean - System.Boolean
- Number - System.Double
- Result Tree Fragment - System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator
- Node Set - System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator

So in your example I would try XPathNodeLiterator.