# Browser-independent way of using DOMDocument in Jscript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-9, domdocument

What is the best way to create browser-independent Jscript code in which a DOMDocument has to be created?
I have this code (extracted from @MartinHonnen 's answer to my question [How can make an XSLT Javascript extension function return a node-set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222750/how-have-an-xslt-javascript-extension-function-return-a-node-set)):

```
function tokenize (input) {
    var doc = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
    ...
    }
```

which worked fine in an MSXML 6.0 XSLT processor (note that the Jscript is embedded in an xslt sheet) and in IE9 (although strangely enough not every time - stepping into debug mode seems to help a bit here), but didn't do so good in IE8, where the class had to be changed to `Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0` to get it working properly. Apparently IE8 Jscript supports MSXML 3.0 but not higher versions.

So now I am looking for browser-type and browser-version independent code making use of DOMDocument.
Who can provide me with this?
I added `Jquery` as a tag because the best solution may be found there.
Side-question: where can I find an overview of which DOM class is supported by which browser type+version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tweak `CreateXmlHttpReq` function to handle different types of Microsoft's ActiveXObjects

```
function CreateXmlHttpReq(handler) {
    var xmlhttp = null;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var types = ["Msxml2.XMLHTTP.6.0", "Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0", "Microsoft.XMLHTTP"];

        for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
            try {
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject(types[i]);
                break;
            } catch(e) {}
        }
    }

    if (xmlhttp) {
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handler;
    }

    return xmlhttp;
}
```

Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389829/1237812

Comment: For that I will need to know the list of DOM classes available per browser type+version :-(