# XSL getText() localization using PO file not picking up the localized text

Tags: xslt, localization, gettext, po

Using XSLT we are trying to generate some HTML for localization using from po files,
the problem is that it is unable to pick the localized text, 
e.g. the entry in xsl file:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(t:gettext('Get real time {0} Posts',$name))" />
```

and the entry in the po file for the same:

```
msgid "Get real time {0} Posts"
msgstr "إحصل على الإعلانات من {0} في الوقت الحقيقي"
```

This is always displaying the msgid, I suspect this is something to do with the usage of getText().

Any help on the same is highly appreciated.

Comment: Your function `t:gettext` is not available in XSLT by default. Can you show its definition? Also, say what is denoted by `$name`.

Comment: name is <xsl:variable name="name" select="name" />

Comment: possible duplicate of [How have an xslt javascript extension function return a node-set?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222750/how-have-an-xslt-javascript-extension-function-return-a-node-set)